# <ui:include> with dynamic src does not invoke setters on backingbean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a `first.jsf` in which I include `second.xhtml` in the following way:

```
<ui:include src="#{firstBean.srcForSecond}" />
```

This works fine and renders the contents of `second.jsf`. I included it using EL as the included content changes based on some conditions.

My `second.xhtml` contains a simple input text box:

```
<h:inputText id="firstname" value="#{secondBean.firstName}" />
```

When I load the page the value for firstname is rendered properly. However, when I change the value in the text box and submit, the setter on the backing bean is never invoked.

However if I change the `ui:include` in the following way, it works:

```
<ui:include src="second.xhtml" />
```

But, I require to use EL expression as it could be `second.xhtml` or `third.xhtml` based on some conditions.

Can anybody explain whats going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I think there is some information missing here. Did you have some code you meant to include?

Comment: @Feanor: the OP entered XML code plain in question instead of using code formatting (indent with 4 spaces), which caused that it becomes invisble. I've fixed the code formatting in the question so that it becomes visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `#{firstBean}` a [`@ViewScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) bean instead of a [`@RequestScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html) one. This way you ensure that `#{firstBean.srcForSecond}` evaluates the same in the subsequent request. It's namely re-evaluated during apply request values phase of the form submit. If it evaluates differently, then the originally included components can't be located and nothing will be set/invoked.

Comment: Thats it! My firstBean.srcForSecond method was not returning consistent results. Thanks very much for your response.